# imwarp function block in simulink

Tags: matlab, simulink

I need to create a block in Simulink to deform a video streaming.
I create this code for the 'Interpreted MATLAB Fcn' block of Simulink:

```
function B = deformation(A,tform)
%#codegen

B=imwarp(A,tform);
```

For me now the problem is:

- how to create the block to provide the input of tform that is a structure
- how to manage A, that is the signal from 'From Video device' block in Simulink

I already tested imwarp function for a static image, and I've already calculated tform values as input to imwarp

Is there a method to update calculated tform on a block of simulink. They should no change

Answer (score 1):

There are 3 ways to use Matlab functions in simulink.

- Interpreted Matlab functions
- level 1 Matlab s-functions
- level 2 Matlab s-functions

Personally I neither like level 1 s-functions nor interpreted Matlab functions. For level 1 s-functions you gotta tell simulink which functions you plan to use, similar to an include.
Interpreted Matlab functions are pretty restricted so I'd suggest you a level 2 Matlab s-function, as soon as you intend to do a little advanced stuff.

Also I'd suggest you to use 3 dimensional arrays instead of structs, a picture is a x*y*3 array which you can use in a simulink-block. You can use setInputDimension to get the input-size and set the output size according to your wishes (level 2 s-function).

Also if your problems is just the format struct you can write a simple script which transforms the struct into a three dimensional array, wich is no issue for simulink (in this case you can go with the interpreted matlab function).

At last: I am pretty sure you can't use structs to pass data between simulink blocks, except you read and write to the base workspace, and infact pass no real information between your blocks.

I hope that helped a little.

Comment: Sorry, but there are some unclear stuff in your answers. What is the difference between level 1 and level 2 of s-functions? Could you link some more detailed examples to better understand the examples? You suggested to use an interpreted matlab function to convert from struct to matrix. Why and ho to do that? Could you link some similar solved problems. Thanks

Comment: @SPS: I don't have much time now, so I'll be quick. You can find diverent examples about s-function in Simulink, go to the library, click on user-defined functions, click on s-function examples. Also if you are interested in s-function I'd suggest to visit this link: [Mathworks-page](http://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/sfg/writing-level-2-matlab-s-functions.html?nocookie=true). Level 1 s-functions ain't recommended, due to their restricted use, and due to the fact that it ain't much work to update it to level 2.

Comment: @SPS: Lastly I said to do two things in your interpreted Matlab function, one is your imwarp and the other is the transform from struct to array. I know that simulink can handle three dimensional arrays, but I doubt it can handle structs. The reason is I don't know how to set a struct dimension as simulink input-dimension, and that Simulink has no chance to specify the wished data in a multilayer struct. Hence you take your struct, extract all data you wish to use, and put it together along the third dimension into an array. I might write you a simple example when I have some more time.

Comment: Is there someone that could explain how to write code for a MATLAB function in Simulink to operate imwarp function and to manage input and output in/out the block? Or anyway could you indicate some tutorials? Thanks